# How do I create this effect of instantaneous typing in a video?

Tags: effects, visual-effects

I have seen in many videos where I see a cursor blinking and then something(maybe the name of a person) is typed out in the video producing an effect of the thing being instantaneously typed out.How do I create this effect?I use Videopad Video Editor and MS PowerPoint.Is it possible to do this using these softwares?If not,please suggest some alternatives.

See this video at 2:18 sec for example-

.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @AdamMannPro-I have edited the question.See it.

Answer (score 2):

Sony Vegas Pro comes bundled with NewBlue Titler plugin which has a 'Type On' transition preset which does this automatically. After Effects can do this as well: see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=q3lXwSnuRUA).

Basically, this can be done manually in any program in which one can animate masks. In short, in one frame the mask shape extends till the edge of the currently revealed letters. It is keyframed to hold that shape till one frame before you are ready to reveal the next letter. On that next frame, you expand the mask to uncover the new character.